# Is there a euphemism we could use, say, once a week, just to vent?

Tags: discussion

It gets very frustrating sometimes when you invest time and energy into putting together an answer, and the OP doesn't appreciate it or understand it, and tops it off with a downvote.

I mean, yeah, it's all right - when it happens once. Twice. I can take four in a row without batting an eye. Patience is a virtue, up to six times. But there's virtue and then there's masochism, and once you've been insulted seven times in a row, the line begins very gradually to blur.

I propose each member be granted the right to use an offensive acronym in a comment at least once a week.

Comment: How about "DNFTT" for "Do Not Feed The Trolls"?

Comment: That would be admonishing fellow sufferers rather than telling off an obnoxious moron.

Comment: ["That's ten in a row. Maybe it's me."](http://dilbert.com/strip/2000-07-25)

Comment: Also, maybe take a break and come back when your battery is topped up.  Vacation works, dude.

Comment: I don't see/read anyone laughing with you, Ricky. This must tell you something. Perhaps in person you come across as being eccentric, an intellectual and/or charming. Maybe your tone of voice, a smile, a wink would excuse your rudeness but on page, be it virtual or non, it comes off as being "attention whore". I think that's the modern-day expression.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I hope you flagged this as offensive or needs moderator attention.

Comment: @Ricky - did it ever cross your mind that this site  is probably not the best place for you for which  to spend your time and energy? Reading between the lines...since we are all OPs you are clearly being offensive to the entire community.

Comment: I see there has been a curfew of sorts. Now that the post has been cleaned up, with what looks like 50% of the comments purged, what's the point in keeping *any* of the previous comments? VTC retracted.

Comment: OMG, Ricky's been suspended, again.

Comment: I think one-year suspension is too harsh...

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Are you really surprised? He practically demanded it be delivered on a silver platter.

Answer (score 12):

Absolutely not. It will be flagged as offensive, abbreviation or not.

Six "offensive" flags on a post (or one moderator's "offensive" flag) will result in a 100-rep penalty applied automatically, and runs the risk of suspension. Offensive comments are removed by fewer flags, but if there are enough of those then again there is a risk of suspension.